# UPDATE SQL A TRAVES DE SUBCONSULTAS

Tags: mysql, sql, c++, oracle

el problema que tengo es que quiero actualizar una tabla mediante una subconsulta ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
-- -> SUMA DE LOS SALDOS 
 Al hacer este select me suma los datos correctamente , cómo haría para actualizarlos , en vez   
 de mostrarlos , espero se entienda , soy nuevo en esto..
select c.dniCliente,c.nombre, c.saldo + sum(d.cantidadDeposito) 
from clientes as c inner join depositos as d on c.dniCliente = d.cliente group by 
c.dniCliente;


-- TABLA ACTUALIZAR SALDO
update clientes c
inner join depositos d on c.dniCliente = d.cliente
set c.saldo = (select c.saldo + sum(d.cantidadDeposito)) 
where c.dniCliente = '12345678';
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es integrar la consulta como toda una tabla y hacer el join con la tabla a actualizar. Tu sentencia update quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE c 
SET c.saldo = result.saldo 
FROM clientes c 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1.dniCliente, t1.saldo + SUM(t2.cantidadDeposito) AS saldo
    FROM clientes AS t1 
    INNER JOIN depositos AS t2 ON t1.dniCliente = t2.cliente 
    GROUP BY t1.dniCliente
) result ON c.dniCliente = result.dniCliente
WHERE c.dniCliente = '12345678';
```

Cabe aclarar que esto es tomando en cuenta que trabajas sobre el motor MYSQL. Quizá en otros motores sea diferente la integración

Comment: Muchas gracias , me sirvió mucho estaba combatiendo con todo esto, de verdad muchas gracias.

Comment: No hace falta que meta la subquery como una "subtabla", con hacer el inner join tal y como lo hace en la subquery, es suficiente, de esa forma, no le hace falta el group by, ya que es un filtro y no lo necesita sacar en la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

siguiendo la recomendación que hice en la solución que comentó el compañero, te dejo el resultado de lo que yo haría.

```
UPDATE c 
SET c.saldo = c.saldo + SUM(d.cantidadDeposito)
FROM clientes c 
INNER JOIN depositos AS d ON c.dniCliente = d.cliente 
WHERE c.dniCliente = '12345678';
```

Prueba algo así.

Un saludo!